# Zapf dingbats for use with pdftex option to hyperref package?

Tags: fonts, hyperref, pdf

I'm trying to use pdflatex to process the `ex0001.tex` example file that comes with the pdf-forms-tutorial (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/pdf-forms-tutorial?lang=en).

I hit the fatal error:

```
pdflatex (file zd______.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

As I understand this, it means I don't have the Type 1 Zapf dingbats font installed.  I looked for sources to buy them, but the only Zapf dingbats I find available now are in OpenType format.

Snag:

- the OpenType would require using xelatex instead of pdflatex; but
- the `ex0001.tex` file includes the `pdftex` option, among pdf-related options, to the needed `hyperref` package.

```latex
\usepackage[
  pdftex,colorlinks=true,
  pdftitle={Key form},pdfsubject={Key},
  pdfauthor={ich},pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH,
  pagebackref,pdfhighlight={/N}
]{hyperref}
```

The source includes also:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{phv}
```

**Questions:**

1. If I must use only the OpenType format of the Zapf dingbats, and hence xelatex, I know I must remove the `pdftex` option from the call to `hyperref` and, I presume, replace it with the `xetex` option. Will that still produce satisfactory pdf forms?
2. The `inputenc` package is not intended for use with xetex. So how do I reconcile all this with the apparent necessity to use xelatex?

The complete source is:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{phv}
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{ABC, Inc.}\chead{}\rhead{XYZ Dept.}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[
  pdftex,a4paper=true,colorlinks=true,
  pdftitle={Key form},pdfsubject={Key},
  pdfauthor={ich},pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH,
  pagebackref,pdfhighlight={/N}
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Request for a key}
\begin{Form}
\textbf{Employee}\\
First name: \TextField[name=vorname]{}\\
Name: \TextField[name=name]{}\\
Department: \ChoiceMenu[name=abt]{}{%
Sales=v,Production=f,Service=s}\\
\textbf{Time}\\
Time: \ChoiceMenu[name=zeit]{}{%
limited=b,unlimited=u}\\
from: \TextField[name=from]{}\\
until: \TextField[name=until]{}\\
\textbf{Doors}\\
Front door: \CheckBox[name=ht]{}\\
Ground floor: \CheckBox[name=e1]{}\\
First floor: \CheckBox[name=e2]{}\\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a full example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` instead of many snippets. The `pdftex` option should *never* be specified.

Comment: Usually the package code is smart enough to figure out which driver to use by itself. I got the forms working with XeTeX by simply removing the `pdftex` option and removing the `inputenc` and `fontenc` lines.

Comment: The example compiles fine on a current system with pdflatex and uses fonts/type1/urw/zapfding/uzdr.pfb. Somethings seems to be wrong with your map-files if it tries to use zd_____.pfb.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Am I correct that having "LW35 ADOBE" in my local texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg is what is "wrong" with my map files? Note that I still want to use those genuine Adobe Type 1 fonts that I have, including Times, etc.

Comment: Yes, if the map contains an entry for the zap dingbats you could replace it and then run updmap-sys.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I changed `LW35 ADOBE` in my `~/Librarytexmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` to `LW35 URWkb` and ran `updmap-user` (on advice from Herb Schulz on the OS X TeX mailing list) -- and *not* `updmay-sys`. That fixed the problem, as there were no `Map *.map` entries in my `updmap.cfg` that, in turn, referred to  the Adobe name `zd______`. (I belive I can simply delete that line from my local `updmap.cfg`, since it's already in the system `updmap.cfg`.) And so XeTeX has nothing to to with it.